# Compare two numbers declared as string

Tags: excel, vba

There are two variables. I assign them two numbers given below.

```
   Dim string a,b 
   a="100" and b="65" 
   if a<=b ? True Why?
```

I want the result to be false.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Because Strings are not Numbrrs.  If you want to compare them as Numbers, convert them to numbers first.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at the basic concepts of [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) und maybe it is also a good idea to understand [orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect, I guess its because you wrote some pseudo-code to explain the problem. Its better to copy/paste the real code.

The reason is that your variables are declared as **strings** and not **numbers**.

So the first "letter" of `a` is `1` and the first "letter" of `b` is `6` -> 1 is  smaller than 6

You should do :

```
   Dim a as Integer
   Dim b as Integer

   a=100 
   b=65

   if a<=b then

   end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings not numbers. Also, you would need String after a and b if this were VBA.

Change your declarations.

```
Dim a As Long, b As Long
a=100
b=65
Msgbox a <= b
```